# How to use R.swift for string and colors

Tags: ios, swift, typechecking

So I have a simple question.I searched a lot and there was no such a clear answer to my question.
How can I use R.swfit for Colors and Localized String ?
R.swift completely recognize my images and fonts but how can I use them for my Colors and Localized.
I have so many colors and Localized String in my Project but `R.string` and `R.color` are empty at all

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer.I was wrong about working of R.swift.for using Colors you have to define them in `Assets.xcassets` as a new color set.after creating colors there you can use them via `R.color`.

For using `R.string` you have to create a new `File.string` file in your project and define your strings in a key-value format like `"variable" = "something";`. After that, you can use `R.string.File.variable()` to use those strings.

Comment: When I have raw png stored in resource folder unlike xcasset, is it possible to use R.Swift?